# Python, Tkinter, SQL: How can I pass a variable from 1 frame to another?

Tags: python, sql, oop, tkinter

So I have spent some time digging around and cannot seem to find an answer to this, hoping someone with more experience can help me :D

I'm building a simple CRM App which includes a search function. One the 'Search' Frame the user can input their search query and click the 'Search' button. This will then query the database and populate the results on a new 'Search Results' Frame

While I can extract the user input from the 'Search' Frame and even run the SQL query, I cannot find a way to pass this result into the 'Search Results' Frame.

I have included the relevant code below - if anyone could point me in the right direction it would be fantastic!

As an aside, I have noted that other similar questions have been asked and answered but I cannot seem to get the solutions to work on my side - I'm not a Python expert by any means so perhaps I am missing something

```
.
.
.

### SEARCH WINDOW
class SearchFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self,parent)
        self.title = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text="Search")
        self.title.pack()

        self.searchBar = ctk.CTkEntry(self)
        self.searchBar.pack()

        self.searchBtn = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Search", command=lambda: self.search(controller,self.searchBar.get()))
        self.searchBtn.pack()


### THIS IS WHERE I AM STRUGGLING ###

    def search(self, controller, query):
        self.sql = f"SELECT * FROM Companies WHERE Name LIKE '%{query}%'"
        results = Db.query(self.sql)

### If I were to run For Row in Results: print(Row) here, this works so I know the db & query are working correctly

        controller.show_frame(SearchResultsFrame)


### SEARCH RESULTS WINDOW
class SearchResultsFrame(SearchFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
            ctk.CTkFrame.__init__(self,parent)

### HOW CAN I PULL THE ABOVE RESULT INTO HERE:
            for row in SearchFrame.search.results:
                print(row)

            self.title = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text='Search Results')
            self.title.pack()

            self.companies_title = ctk.CTkLabel(self, text='Companies:')
            self.companies_title.pack()

            ### Display results in a TreeView using these columns:
            self.searchResults_columns = [
                'Name',
                'Industry',
                'Postcode',
                'Status'
            ]

            ### Create the TreeView using the above columns and then format for display:
            self.searchResults_tree = ttk.Treeview(self, columns=self.searchResults_columns, show='headings')
       
            Functions.treeFormat(self.searchResults_columns,self.searchResults_tree)
            self.searchResults_tree.pack(expand=True, fill='both')


            self.home_btn = ctk.CTkButton(self, text="Home", command=lambda: controller.show_frame(DashboardFrame))
            self.home_btn.pack()  
.
.
.
```

Originally, SearchResultsFrame was a CTkFrame instance like SearchFrame. After some more research I tried making it an instance of SearchFrame to see if I could pull it through that way but no luck.

I know I could set a global variable and pull it that way but my understanding is that would be bad practice so I'm trying to avoid doing it that way.

I have also tried simply accessing it directly via SearchFrame.searchBar.get() within the context of the Search Results Frame. If the frame is an instance of SearchFrame then I get a blank value, if it is an instance of CTkFrame, then I get an error

Similarly, I seen a solution which declared a variable before the **init** function which could later be addressed as, for example, SearchResults.queryText but again, I can't seem to get it working.

Comment: `tkinter` offers `set()` and `get()` methods, which are usually the best way to do this....

Answer (score 0):

Solved it :)

I realised that SearchResultsFrame wasn't 'reloading' when I used the show_frame function because the code had already been loaded before hand using the **init** function.

I added a method to my SearchResultsFrame and then called it from my 'search' method and this seems to be working

```
### SEARCH WINDOW
class SearchFrame(ctk.CTkFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
       ##Same code as initial question
    
    def search(self, controller, query):
       controller.show_frame(SearchResultsFrame)

       **SearchResultsFrame.populate_page(self,query)**

class SearchResultsFrame(SearchFrame):
    def __init__(self,parent,controller):
        ##Same code as initial question

    **def populate_page(self, query):
        print(query)**
```

Answer (score 0):

it seems that you have posted an answer to your own question, but i shall add this anyway as this might add to your knoledge. `tkinter` offers the `set()` and `get()` methods specifically for parsing variables without the need for `globals` or other tricks.

Here is an example:

```py
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()

my_var = tk.StringVar()
my_var.set("Hello")

def click_button():
    value = my_var.get()
    my_var.set(value + " World!")

button = tk.Button(root, text="Click Me", command=click_button)
button.pack()

label = tk.Label(root, textvariable=my_var)
label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```